# Selecionar o valor de um campo dependendo de uma data

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, pl-sql

Tenho uma tabela com os campos `DT_FIMCALCULO, VL_DEPREREVVIDAUTILACUMULADA e CD_SEQUENCIALBEM`.

E para cada `CD_SEQUENCIALBEM` tenho várias `DT_FIMCALCULO` cada uma com um `VL_DEPREREVVIDAUTILACUMULADA` diferente.

Quero selecionar o `VL_DEPREREVVIDAUTILACUMULADA` onde a `DT_FIMCALCULO` for igual a *30/09/2016*.

Porém nem todos os Bens possuem calculo em *30/09*, alguns possuem calculo somente até *31/05/2016* por exemplo, e neste caso quero o `VL_DEPREREVVIDAUTILACUMULADA` desta ultima data.

Minha consulta **SQL** ficou assim:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(DT_FIMCALCULO) AS DT_FIMCALCULO, CD_SEQUENCIALBEM, 
    VL_DEPREREVVIDAUTILACUMULADA
FROM
    TB_DEPRECIACAOSOCIETARIACAL
WHERE
    DT_FIMCALCULO <= '2016-09-30'
AND
    CD_SEQUENCIALBEM = 20
GROUP BY
    CD_SEQUENCIALBEM, VL_DEPREREVVIDAUTILACUMULADA
ORDER
    BY DT_FIMCALCULO
```

Ao selecionar o campo `MAX(DT_FIMCALCULO)` quero que me traga a data *30/09* ou então a maior data que seja menor que esta... Tipo *30/08* ou *31/05* por exemplo.

Porém como o campo `VL_DEPREREVVIDAUTILACUMULADA` possui valores diferentes, o **SQL** continua resultando todas as datas menores que *30/09*, mas eu não quero isto.

Quero apenas 1 resultado para cada `CD_SEQUENCIALBEM`.
Este resultado tem que ser a Data *30/09* ou menor que ela, e o valor referente a esta data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM TB_DEPRECIACAOSOCIETARIACAL A1
WHERE CD_SEQUENCIALBEM = 20
AND DT_FIMCALCULO = (SELECT MAX(DT_FIMCALCULO) AS DT_FIMCALCULO, 
                     FROM TB_DEPRECIACAOSOCIETARIACAL A2
                     WHERE A2.DT_FIMCALCULO <= '2016-09-30'
                     AND A2.CD_SEQUENCIALBEM = 20)
GROUP BY CD_SEQUENCIALBEM, VL_DEPREREVVIDAUTILACUMULADA
ORDER BY DT_FIMCALCULO
```

Um subselect com MAX resolve o problema.

Comment: Genial, como não pensei nisso kkk... Só tive que fazer uma adaptação pois eu precisava de todos os Bens e não só do Seq 20... adicionei no subselect A1.CD_SEQUENCIALBEM = A2.CD_SEQUENCIALBEM assim trouxe todos os bens, e cada um com sua Max(dt_fimcalculo) ... Enfim ficou perfeito. Muito obrigado.